# Gradle - 'flatten' default resource directory

Tags: gradle

in my project I've the following directory setup:

- `src/main/resources/common`
- `src/main/resources/local`
- `src/main/resources/release`

My goal is to override the default resources elaboration and to "flatten" this directory tree in the final archive.

At the moment I found only this ugly solution:

```
resources {
  exclude 'release'
  exclude 'common'
  exclude 'local'
  srcDir 'src/main/resources/common'
  srcDir 'src/main/resources/local'
  srcDir 'src/main/resources/release'
}
```

With this solution I think that the files in `src/main/resources` will be copied in the final archive. Is there a way to exclude the resources default directory?

Is there any better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to override the default locations:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = [
                'src/main/resources/common', 
                'src/main/resources/local',
                'src/main/resources/release'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It's a common idiom for Gradle APIs to offer a *property* (such as `srcDirs`) that allows to set a collection (thereby overriding any defaults), and a similarly named *method* (such as `srcDir`) that allows to add to the collection (thereby adding to the defaults).

> My goal is to [...] "flatten" this directory tree in the final archive.

Not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

What if we don't wish to explicity give each directly..can flatten happen as in ant it is happens with flatten attribute as in

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/flatten-directories-during-copy-with-java-ant-task/

Comment: This is so hard to read that it gives the impression of asking a question instead of trying to answer the question at the top of the page. You are try to answer, aren't you?